# difference in reading XML from source code manually copied and programmatically generated by PHP

Tags: php, xml

I did PHP coding using an XML file whose source code I copied manually, it looks like

```
<title type='text'>content I've extracted</title>
<content type='text'>content I've extracted</content>
```

Now everything is done and when I generate the content by PHP coding and when I try to extract the things from title and content tags the output is not generated...when I cross checked I found the PHP generated file (source code, RSS feed)looks like

```
<title type=\'text\'>content to be extracted </title>
<content type=\'text\'>content to be extracted</content>
```

As there are backward slashes it is not able to extract the content, I guess

The sample PHP code which I'm using to get contents from those tags is

```
  $titles = $entry->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
  $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $descrs = $entry->getElementsByTagName( "content" );
  $descr = $descrs->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

How can I proceed?

This is the PHP code which I used to generate XML

```
$url='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/12345';
$fp = fopen($url, 'r'); 
$buffer='';
if ($fp) {
while (!feof($fp))
$buffer .= fgets($fp, 1024);
fclose($fp);
file_put_contents('feed.xml', $buffer);
```

---

**I found the solution**

```
$buff=stripslashes($buffer);
file_put_contents('ka.xml', $buff);
```

so `stripslashes()` function removes backslash and it works

Comment: Do not proceed with the proken XML, and showing what you want when the XML is OK does not really help. Can you show us how you create / get this broken XML?

Comment: If that's your WHOLE XML file, then I don't know how you are getting anything to work.  Can you post all of the XML, as well as the code you use to load the XML, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) enabled.

> If `magic_quotes_runtime` is enabled, most functions that return data from any sort of external source including databases and text files will have quotes escaped with a backslash.

So when you use fgets to read in the file, any quotes will be escaped. Magic Quotes are deprecated as of PHP 5.3. You should not use them in your script.

Also see http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

---

On a sidenote, your approach to copy the file is much more complicated than it needs to be. All of these would work for saving the remote XML to a file:

```
$src = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/E6DE6EC9A373AF57?v=2';
copy($src, 'dest.xml');
```

or

```
$src = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/E6DE6EC9A373AF57?v=2';
file_put_contents('dest.xml', file_get_contents($src));
```

or

```
$src = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/E6DE6EC9A373AF57?v=2';
stream_copy_to_stream(fopen($src, 'r'), fopen('dest.xml', 'w+'));
```